# Being able to pull from multiple worksheets by keying its name in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm working on a forecasting model.  I have (Ex) 100 stores.  I'm sending sales reps to 7 stores every 2 weeks and need to predict based on store performance the number of units I send with the Sales Rep.  I would like to create a Spread Sheet, where each store # is an individual work sheet in that SS, and when I key the Store # in a cell, the TREND information calculated on that Stores WorkSheet will populate on the MAIN Spread Sheet.

Can I do that, and is there a particular function that would pull from that particular variabled work sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to key a store # into a cell on the main spread sheet to achieve this.  If you have "Store 1" and "Store 2", for example, as separate worksheets inside the spreadsheet, the main tab can reference calculated fields, or a range of cells by simply using the formula `='Store 1'!C2` where the specific store's worksheet name is in single quotes, followed by an exclamation point, followed by the cell on that sheet you want to display. You can do this for multiple cells to show as much data from the other sheets as needed.

This will update the main tab's data real-time as the individual store numbers and calculations are updated.  I have a sample [here](http://db.tt/6mB6ITTe) for some hands-on experience.